# TeamCity available only from local. No Firewall. Why isn't it available remotely?

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity, remote-access

So I followed this [guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server) to install TeamCity on a Amazon EC2 install.Everything is working smoothly.

When use Lynx to http://localhost:8111, it works.
Proof:
   TeamCity

```
TeamCity Maintenance

   Confirming TeamCity first start
   Please enable JavaScript in your browser to access TeamCity.
   TeamCity 8.0.5 (build 27692)
```

lsof -i output:

```
java     13224     root   38u  IPv6 1346958      0t0  TCP *:8111 (LISTEN)
```

`iptables -L` is accepting everything.

Also, reading the logs, I see:

```
[2015-06-02 12:23:47,595]   WARN -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Could not determine the local IP address: ip-10-0-81-70: ip-10-0-81-70: Name or service not known
```

So I tried adding the IP in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8111" address="public.ip.ad.ress"  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol">
```

Start & stop. Still the same problem, can't access from publicip:8111.

This [tutorial](http://pedroreys.com/2011/05/23/running-teamcity-on-ec2/) seem to say I don't even need to do that:

Where did I fail ?

Comment: Just for testing, I yum -y install httpd and started it.
I cannot access it by ip. I think I need to use the DNS name and not the IP. Can anyone confirm this ?

Comment: Still not working.. can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

I am using AWS and their security rules were acting as a firewall.
Just added a rule to allow traffic from port 8111 and 80 and now it works !